# Ionic 2-3 *ngIf doesn't update the view

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic application in version 3.

I have a side menu (toggle menu) which is defined in app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" (ionClose)="menuClosed()(ionOpen)="menuOpened()">
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <button menuClose ion-item (click)="toggleHelp()">
        <ion-icon item-start name="help-circle"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Help</ion-label>
    </button>
</ion-content>
```

In the file app.component.ts, there is this function:

```
private toggleHelp = () =>{
  this.helpClicked = true;
  this.homePage.showHelp();
}
```

In my home page, I have a card that explain stuff. The user can hide it and if the user opens the sidemenu, he can click on the button Help (that is declared on the sidemenu) and it will show the card again.

home.html looks like:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content no-padding>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
  <ion-card margin *ngIf="(help_shown == true)" class="card-help">
<span class="button_acknowledgement">
  <button ion-button clear color="bluelight" (click)="hideHelp()">I GOT IT</button>
</span>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

in the home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {

  help_shown = true;

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private zone: NgZone) {
  }
    private hideHelp = () =>{
      this.help_shown = false;
      console.log("help_shown: "+this.help_shown)
    }
public showHelp = () =>{
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.help_shown = true;
      console.log("help_shown: "+this.help_shown)
    });        
}
```

So now, when i click on the button I got it, the card will be hidden (because the variable help_shown will be changed to false). When I click on help inside the menuside, the variable help_shown will be modified by the function (it will pass at true, I logged it so i'm sure it is working), however the card does not appear even thought the *ngIf should do it appears. I tried with the ngZone, but without success. Can somebody help me please?

PS : If i create a button inside the homepage, that will change the variable help_shown, it will work as well.

You can try what i say here: https://ionic-n35gsm.stackblitz.io

Comment: just a quick hint: this is not an "angularjs" problem, but an "angular" one

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Thank you

Comment: You can try what i say here : https://ionic-n35gsm.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

Change

From

```
<ion-card margin *ngIf="(help_shown == true)" class="card-help">
```

To

```
<ion-card margin *ngIf="help_shown" class="card-help">
```

Comment: It does the same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you run into some scope problem because you defined your functions as variables. Try changing them as follows:

```
hideHelp() {
  this.help_shown = false;
}

showHelp() {
  this.help_shown = true;
}
```

And as @Sajeetharan already mentioned you do not need to explicitly compare a boolean variable to `true` or `false`.

Comment: I think you are right on the scope. When the reference is not on the home page, but is moved to the app.component.ts, the scope will be different.  I believe using a component and then the Output needs the event to trigger the update.

Comment: @StevenScott Thanks for your input put `help_shown` still stays an instance variable, so he can just access it using `this` no need to call a function.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I will remove that comment as I was thinking of something else (button functions) and not things in the question.

Comment: Hello, your solution doesn't change anything. I think it is a scoop problem, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: I will have a look and let you know!

Comment: @Junior you need to provide a stackblitz link where I can fork and edit the code, not just the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setTimeout()` and let me know.

*.html*

```
 <ion-card margin *ngIf="help_shown" class="card-help">
```

*.ts*

```
   help_shown:boolean = true;

   constructor(private platform: Platform) {
     }

    showHelp(){
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.help_shown = true;
       },500);        
    }
```

Comment: Hello, i had already tried this solution. But it doesn't work as well :(

Comment: Hey here you go : https://ionic-n35gsm.stackblitz.io (simulation) 
And edition link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-n35gsm

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem by declaring a Event in the menuside when the button is pressed. And on the HomePage there is a event listener on the constructor.